# QML Spline chart goes beyond upper limit

Tags: qt, charts, qml

I have created a spline chart with percentage in its Y axis (1 to 100) percentage . But for values 90 to 86 graph goes beyond 100. Is there any way to 
overcome this issue

Values appended are - 30,51,60, 66,49,59,22,36,49,79,67,16,35,25,36,30,64,17,90,86,23,30,23

[image]

Comment: that is what returns the interpolation, that does not depend on Qt but the algorithm itself. What kind of output do you expect? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

Comment: No value is beyond 100 . So that chart should not go beyond 100. Especially for percentage . Going beyond 100 % makes no sense

Comment: Have you read the link that happens to you? when you use SplineSeries this will use the Spline interpolation that uses the curvature, he does not know what a percentage is, he will only build a curve where the points that are part of the series belong and the curvature is smooth. Why do not you use LineSeries?

Comment: At those points you give the interpretation of percentages but for the algorithm that implements the curve are points and this will try to join the points with a smooth curve, for this use the curvature. If you do not like it then use LineSeries. :)

Comment: @eyllanesc . Thank you :)

Comment: @eyllanesc: Would you mind moving your last two comments in a short answer, so this question could be marked as completed? Thanks :-)